# Find the vector of minimum norm...

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm working on this exercise:

> Show that the subset $ M = ${$y= (\eta_j) ;  \sum \eta _j= 1$} of
> complex space $\mathbb{C^{n}}$  is complete and convex. Find the
> vector of minimum norm in M.

I've proved the completeness and convexity part, but I could not find the minimizing vector. I have the suspicion that it's $(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n},...,\frac{1}{n})$, but I couldn't find an argument.

Could you help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This also follows directly from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n \eta_j=\sum_{j=1}^n \eta_j\cdot 1\leq \left(\sum_{j=1}^n |\eta_j|^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{j=1}^n 1\right)^{1/2}=n^{1/2}\left(\sum_{j=1}^n |\eta_j|^2\right)^{1/2}
$$
With equality if and only if there exists $\lambda\geq 0$ such that $\eta_j=\lambda$ for all $j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. The constraint $\sum_j \eta_j=1$ is then satisfied if and only if $\lambda=1/n$.

Comment: Why can we restrict to $\lambda \geq 0$? I remember that equality holds iff one is a scalar multiple (lambda could be negative, is it not so?) of the other.

Comment: The equality with an absolute value on the left side holds iff one is a scalar multiple of the other. But in this case we don't have an absolute value on the left side, which restricts the range of the scalars to positive reals. In any case, you could also conclude with $\lambda\in \mathbb C$.

Answer (score 0):

Your conjecture is correct. You can view this problem as a constraint optimization problem:
$$
\min\sum_j(a_j^2+b_j^2)\quad\text{s.t.}\;\sum_ja_j=1,\;\sum_jb_j=0.
$$
Set $f(a,b) = \sum_j(a_j^2+b_j^2)$, $g(a,b) = \sum_ja_j - 1$, and $h(a,b)=\sum_jb_j$. Then
$$
f'(a,b) = 2(a,b),\quad g'(a,b) = (\mathbf{1},0), \quad\text{and}\quad h'(a,b) = (0,\mathbf{1}).
$$
By Lagrange, if $(a,b)$ is an optimum, there exist numbers $\lambda,\mu$ such that
$$
f'(a,b) = \lambda g'(a,b) + \mu h'(a,b).
$$
Hence,
$$
2(a,b) = \lambda(\mathbf 1,0) + \mu(0,\mathbf 1) = (\lambda,\ldots,\lambda,\mu,\ldots,\mu).
$$
Therefore, we have $a_1=\ldots=a_n$ and $b_1 =\ldots = b_n$. The restrictions $g(a,b)=0$ and $h(a,b)=0$ now imply that $a_j = \frac 1n$ for all $j$ and $b_j = 0$ for all $j$, hence $\eta_j = \frac 1n$ for all $j$.